# A tangential fixed point property for manifolds embedded in Euclidean spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, fixed-point-theorems

Assume that $M$ is  a compact orientable manifold which is embedded in some  Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ 
We say that $M\subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ has the tangential fixed point property if for  every continuous $f:M\to M$ there is  a  point $a\in M$ such that $T_{a}M \parallel T_{f(a)} M$? (the later parallelism is well defined since we live in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$)

Example: For $N=2k+1$ put $M=S^{2k}$. the reason is that for every continuous map on even sphere, there is  a point $a$ with either $f(a)=a$ or $f(a)=-a$.

Compact surfaces with genus different from $1$.  as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, are other examples since their tangent bundle do not admit a subline bundle.

> What are some other examples in higher dimensions? For what type of  compact  manifolds there is  an embedding in some $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with the above tangential fixed point property?
>   Is there an embedding of $S^{2n+1}$ in some $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with the above tangential fixed p[oint property?

**Note:** We can generalize the idea  of "*tangential fixed point property*"  by replacing $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with a  parallelizable or  flat Riemannian manifold.

Comment: If M is n-dimensional and N>n+2, a generic embedding of M will have the property that no two tangent spaces are parallel, so in those dimensions the (generic) question reduces to a fixed point question.  (See also theorem 1 [here](https://www.math.psu.edu/tabachni/prints/skewspheres8.pdf)).  So an interesting example might appear in codimension 1, or maybe certain isolated examples in higher codimension.

Comment: @MichaelHarrison   Thank  you very  much  for  your very interesting comment and helpful information on the concept "Brane".